# Testing ui.router $stateChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I have a simple function in my main controller that updates `$scope.loading` based on ui.router's `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` events.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
  if (toState.resolve) {
    $scope.loading = true;
  }
});
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
  if (toState.resolve) {
    $scope.loading = false;
  }
});
```

This works great until I try to unit test. I can't find a way to trigger the `$stateChangeSuccess` event.

My Jasmine unit test looks something like this:

```
it('should set $scope.loading to true', function () {
    expect(scope.loading).toBe(false);
    $state.go('home');
    expect(scope.loading).toBe(true);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.loading).toBe(false);
});
```

The test fails because `$stateChangeSuccess` never fires. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you update the question with the ancestor beforeEach blocks specific to this test spec?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to trigger the event, you can simply dispatch it yourself. It's not clear what the thing is associated w/the scope in your test case, but `scope.$broadcast('$stateChangeStart');` might be all you need. You can also get the `$rootScope` and broadcast the event from that.

Comment: I think `scope.$broadcast('$stateChangeStart')` is on the right track. I'm curious if the `if (toState.resolve)` is even needed.

Comment: Thanks @SunilD. Can you please answer the question, so it would be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This currently works for me.

You simply need to `$broadcast` the event.  Read below for a bit of pseudocode.  I hope this helps you.

```js
// Note: this is pseudocode

// controller
// assumes you have your usual setup to support this controller.
// assumes this controller is attached to a component or angular controller.

function myController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.isHappy = false;

  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState) {
    if (toState.name === 'myState') {
      vm.isHappy = true;
    }
  });
}

// test
// assumes several things
//    * ctrl is the currently mocked controller
//    * has all the necessary setup & injections (such as $rootScope).
//    * testing framework is Jasmine

describe('What happens when I go to my happy place?', function() {
  it('should be visible to all that I am happy.', function() {
    expect(ctrl.isHappy).toBeFalsy();

    $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', {
      'name': 'myState'
    });
    // or $scope.$broadcast

    expect(ctrl.isHappy).toBeTruthy();
  }
});
```